# Extra word appear in visual c++ output window

Tags: c#, c++, programming-languages, opencv

Everytime I compile and run a program, these extra 2 lines will appear in the beginning of the output window:

> 输入文件 0006E67C不存在
>
> 输入文件 00AB1514不存在

what should i do to clear it ?
tq

Comment: Are you using the official DLLs from OpenCV's website or did you got it from somewhere else?

Comment: I dont know what is Dll. I did not change any setting. I just install the OpenCV and use it. What should i do in order to make sure i am using the correct one?

Answer (score 2):

On [Google translate](http://translate.google.com/#zh-CN%7Cen%7C%20%20%20%20%E8%BE%93%E5%85%A5%E6%96%87%E4%BB%B6%200006E67C%E4%B8%8D%E5%AD%98%E5%9C%A8%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%E8%BE%93%E5%85%A5%E6%96%87%E4%BB%B6%2000AB1514%E4%B8%8D%E5%AD%98%E5%9C%A8%0A) this is translated into:

> 0006E67C input file does not exist
>
> 00AB1514 input file does not exist

Do you have any files that are added to the project but does not exist on disk?

Comment: I have tried by finding through the search box but not found also. Before this i have try find in the project. I cant find it.